# Does the mediation of electric or magnetic force require distinct electron orbitals?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, resonance, virtual-particles, orbitals

In the case of ordinary photons of light, matter interacts with light via electrons that orbit the nucleus. If the specific energy of a photon E = hv can be found in the atom as the energy difference between two orbitals, then the atom can send and receive such photon.

In the case of virtual photons, matter interacts with other matter by virtual photons that carry momentum... Is there any resonant process similar to the above going on?

Comment: matter interacts with light through different types of particules, not only electrons in atoms.

Comment: Can you describe more precisely which "similar resonant process" you think of?

Comment: Photons pass through atoms with or without any interaction with the orbital electrons or nuclei. Interacting photon's energy (1) is equal to potential energy difference (2) within atom. That's "resonance", because both energies (1)(2) can be evaluated using frequencies. Static electricity and magnetism can be represented with field drawings. I would like to present modern drawings of field. Static field redistributes charges in conductors and magnetic field orients some orbitals. Exchange of momentums creates such charge distributions or currents, so what's the frequency of virtual photons?

Comment: This question was infrequently covered in forums over the years with various "no" or confusing answers. Perhaps someone can consider the dielectric constant of a material and propose its "transparency", which in analogy to transparency in optical media may create an imaginative image of the particular percent of resonant interactions that occur within a material, which would be the cause of the given "transparency" for the neighboring electric field.